# Collecting unknown properties with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using Jackson for creating Java objects from JSON. Let's suppose I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"a":"a", "b":"b", "c":"c"}
```

And a pojo like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class A {

    private String a;
    private String b;

    // ...
}
```

So c is clearly an unknown property - and it will be left out. I was wondering, is there any way I can log that c was unknown and ignored?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in tool that does this. You can write your own with `@JsonAnySetter`

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static,
>   two-argument method (first argument name of property, second value to
>   set), to be used as a "fallback" handler for all otherwise
>   unrecognized properties found from JSON content.

Use it like

```
@JsonAnySetter
public void ignored(String name, Object value) {
    // can ignore the 'value' if you only care for the name (though you still need the second parameter)
    System.out.println(name + " : " + value);
}
```

within the class you're deserializing to, eg. your `A` class.

Answer (score 9):

`@JsonAnySetter` when used on a Map field would catch all unmapped properties. When paired with `@JsonAnyGetter` would work for serialization and deserialization:

```
@JsonAnyGetter
@JsonAnySetter
private Map<String, Object> dynamicValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```