# How to ignore Map related braces while converting json to Java object using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm trying to convert JSON to Java object, but I'm having a hard time building Java equivalent object.

My JSON looks like this

```
{
    "point1": {
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 2.0
    },
    "point2": {
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 2.0
    },
    "point3": {
        "x": 1.0,
        "y": 2.0
    },
    "customobject1": "cust1",
    "customobject2": "cust2"
}
```

I need to take **Map** here for points, because there will be n number of points,

```
public class Test {

    public String getCustomobject1() {
        return customobject1;
    }

    public void setCustomobject1(String customobject1) {
        this.customobject1 = customobject1;
    }

    public String getCustomobject2() {
        return customobject2;
    }

    public void setCustomobject2(String customobject2) {
        this.customobject2 = customobject2;
    }

    Map<String, Point> testing  = new HashMap<>();

    String customobject1;
    String customobject2; 

    public Map<String, Point> getTesting() {
        return testing;
    }

    public void setTesting(Map<String, Point> testing) {
        this.testing = testing;
    }

}
```

But I'm getting unrecognized property exception, I know there is a extra wrapper (**{}**) that causes this issue,  Can some body suggest me how to ignore this map name while deserializing JSON?

*Note: Actual object I'm working is bit complex with similar structure, I'm posting just a prototype here.*

Comment: Your "pointX" are really properties of the root object, so Jackson will definitely not map them to "testing" property. Maybe ansther to this other question will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164625/collecting-unknown-properties-with-jackson.

You can assign them to map yourself in the setter

Comment: @uaraven thanks for the info mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't know the keys in advance use [`@JsonAnySetter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAnySetter.html) to map them:

> Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static, two-argument method (first argument name of property, second value to set), to be used as a "fallback" handler for all otherwise unrecognized properties found from JSON content. It is similar to XmlAnyElement in behavior; and can only be used to denote a single property per type.
>
> If used, all otherwise unmapped key-value pairs from JSON Object values are added to the property (of type Map or bean).

```
public class Test  {
  private Map<String, Point> points = new HashMap<>();

  @JsonAnySetter
  public void setPoints(String name, Point value) {
    points.put(name, value);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I actually saw ``@JsonAnySetter`` but I didn't really went through the complete answer , just kept this annoation on my map  setter and expected it to work, but now I realize from your answer  that it should be used on top of fallback method where we well be adding values of unknown properties in it. Feeling kind of dumb.