# Jackson ignore unrecognized property and collect the errors

Tags: java, json, jackson

There are a lot of topics around how can we configure the Jackson to ignore additional properties during the un-marshaller process. But I didn't find any answer how can we ignore it but also collect the unrecognized properties.

Our flow is: We would like to ignore them but collect all of the unrecognized properties in order to be aware of these properties and fix them.

Somebody knows how can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164625/collecting-unknown-properties-with-jackson

Comment: @SebastianHeikamp It can be a solution but it is not a built in approach. Maybe there is a more easy approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using override `DeserializationProblemHandler.handleUnknownProperty` get unknown property name?

```java
public class IgnoreUnknownPropertiesHandler extends DeserializationProblemHandler {
            @Override
            public boolean handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext ctxt, JsonParser p, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer, Object beanOrClass, String propertyName) throws IOException {
                // print ignored property
                System.out.println("Ignored property: " + propertyName);
                return true;
            }
        }
        
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
objectMapper.addHandler(new IgnoreUnknownPropertiesHandler());
```

Comment: This solution brings the minimum code changes. As far as I read there is not a built-in support for this case by Jackson.